# Obtaining a smoothed DTM?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.1, dem, spatial-analyst, smoothing

I am use AcGIS 10.1 and have a DTM with an 8 m grid resolution. Which tool could I apply to smooth the surface?

Comment: Sun's (2007) feature preserving de-noising algorithm works very well in my experience (https://github.com/jblindsay/fp_denoise). I'm not sure if an implementation is available for ArcGIS though.